# Finding the transformation matrix when transformations are given...

Tags: matrices, transformation

Question: For set of vectors {$x_1,x_2$}, $x_1=(1,3)^T, x_2=(4,6)^T$ are in $R^2$. Find the matrix of linear transformation $T:R^2\rightarrow R^3$ such that $Tx_1=(-2,2,-7)^T$ and $Tx_2=(-2,-4,-10)^T$

My attempt: So I'm guessing there exists a matrix (a transformation matrix) and it must be of order (2,3) for it to give (-2,2,-7)$^T$ when multiplied by (1,3)$^T$ :

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
t_{11} & t_{12}\\
t_{21} & t_{22}\\
t_{31} & t_{32}\end{array} \right]$
$\left[ \begin{array}{c}
1\\
3\end{array} \right]$ =
$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
-2\\
2\\
-7\end{array} \right]$

But how am I supposed to find out all those t$_{ij}$ variables? Also, using same on second set of vectors give me inconsistent equations:

$\begin{array}{cc}
t_{11} + 3t_{12} = -2 & 4t_{11} + 6t_{12} = -2\\
t_{21} + 3t_{22} = 2  & 4t_{21} + 6t_{22} = -4\\
t_{31} + 3t_{32} = -7 & 4t_{31} + 6t_{32} = -10\end{array}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier if you use a different vector.  Notice that $x_2-2x_1=(2,0)^T$.  Since you know that $T(x_2-2x_1)=T(x_2)-2T(x_1)$, you can set up a simpler set of equations.  Then try to get a vector $(0,a)^T$, for some $a$.